# PIVOT table only in one row in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[K_RT_GetWareHousedailyReport] 
   @fromdate datetime,
   @todate datetime,
   @branch varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    select 
       MR.Branch, convert(varchar(50), WH.date, 103) as Date,
       WH.NoofBirds, WH.Weight, WH.Meatyield,
       max(case when BT.birdname='Bone Less' then WHT.weight end) as BoneLess,
       max(case when BT.birdname='Skin Less' then WHT.weight end) as SkinLess,
       max(case when BT.birdname='Wings' then WHT.weight end) as Wings,
       max(case when BT.birdname='Liver' then WHT.weight end) as Liver
   from 
       K_RT_WarehouseDetails WH 
   inner join 
       K_RT_WarehouseTypeWeight WHT on WH.sno = WHT.ID
   inner join 
       K_RT_MasterRetailStores MR on MR.sno = WH.branch 
   inner join 
       K_RT_BirdType BT on BT.sno = WHT.[type] 
   where 
       MR.sno = @branch 
       and WH.date between @fromdate And @todate 
   group by 
       BT.birdname, WHT.weight, MR.branch, date, WH.noofbirds, WH.weight, WH.meatyield, WHT.ID 
   order by 
        WHT.ID
END
```

This query returns each row output in four rows but I want only in one row is it possible? I wrote this procedure for pivot table. Please tell me any one.

Comment: how the current output looklike ?you want to pivot on which column base on what ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't group by `BT.birdname` and  `WHT.weight`

```
....
group by MR.branch,date,WH.noofbirds,WH.weight,WH.meatyield,
WHT.ID 
order by WHT.ID
```